# Good book to learn routers and switches

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I'm a developer with a solid understanding of TCP/IP.  I've also done some Linux sys and network administration.  I now need to set up some complicated LANs, and that means learning things like switches and routers (which I have some familiarity with but am no expert) plus all the modern things like VLANs and managed switches (which I've never touched).

I'm looking for a good book on networks and network device.  What I'd like is:
1. Detail rich
2. Not for novices - I don't need handholding, and I don't need screenshots.
3. That will give me *understanding*, not list recipes to follow.

In short, I'd like to really understand everything from ATM to RIP to VLAN, so that I can build and maintain tough LANs.

What books do you recommend? What is their approach?

Answer (score 4):

[Network Warrior](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101511) was written with a heavy Cisco focus, but conceptually was probably the most easily-understood, concisely-written book on the subject of networking that I've ever read. It's practical, and written so you understand how to solve real problems, but it's not written as a list of step-by-step directions. It sounds like it fits the bill.

Comment: +1 network warrior one of the few tech books i've read cover to cover

Comment: _Network Warrior_ is thoroughly great, though completely Cisco-centric.  If that works for you, you'd do well to pick it up.

Comment: Hmmm... my equipment is actually Cisco-less; I'm a bit nervous about a book designed for CCNA.  I found Interconnections: Bridges, Routers, Switches, and Internetworking Protocols (Addison Wesley) on Amazon - anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 4):

Couple of books I have on my shelf:

[Network Warrior](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101511)

[CCNA: Cisco Certified Network Associate Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470110082)

Also you can't go wrong with the [Cisco Exam Prep Stuff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470447257)

I know it's cisco centric, but that's what I learned on, and know the best.

Also if you are going with cisco gear Check out [GNS3](http://gns3.net/) It'll let you virtually model your network first (You need to bring your own IOS images)

Comment: +1 for the concurrent Network Warrior mention :)

Answer (score 0):

I have read earlier versions of Andrew Tanenbaum's *Computer Networks*. At the time, VLANs weren't really among us (this would've been mid-90s), but ATM, Frame Relay and quite a few other network protocols (including Ethernet and Token Ring) were described to the point where I felt that I understood how they worked and were transmitted on the wire.

However, it doesn't necessarily prepare you for how to configure routers and switches.

[Link to publisher's book page](http://authors.phptr.com/tanenbaumcn4/).